# kendoMultiSelect autoClose inside a Template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have a multiselect inside a Kendo template (`type="text/kendo-x-tmpl"`) in a list.
I can't find a way to set property `autoClose` to `false` without jQuery.

```
<script type="text/kendo-x-tmpl" id="tmplRow">
    <td style="width:100%" id="td">
        <select data-id="myId" data-show=""
                multiple="multiple"
                data-role="multiselect"
                data-text-field="Libelle"
                data-value-field="IdProduct"
                data-value-primitive="true"
                data-loading-text="Chargement..."
                data-bind="value: MyList, source: getSource,  events: { select: onSelectedEvent, change: onChangeEvent }" />
    </td>
</script>
```

Any idea would help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is this multiselect a unique element or the <select> element will be inside every td?

Comment: it is in a list. There will be several

Comment: Make sure the id is unique then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the `autoClose` configuration option using this attribute `data-auto-close="false"`:

```
<script type="text/kendo-x-tmpl" id="tmplRow">
    <td style="width:100%" id="td">
        <select data-id="myId" data-show=""
            multiple="multiple"
            data-role="multiselect"
            data-text-field="Libelle"
            data-value-field="IdProduct"
            data-value-primitive="true"
            data-loading-text="Chargement..."
            data-bind="value: MyList, source: getSource,  events: { select: onSelectedEvent, change: onChangeEvent }"
            data-auto-close="false" />
    </td>
</script>
```

The [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/mvvm-initialization) gives this guidance:

> Each configuration option can be set with the data attribute of the target element. Add the `"data-"` prefix to the name of the configuration option and specify the option value—for example, `data-delay="100"`.
>
> The camelCase options are set through dash-separated attributes. For example, the `ignoreCase` option of the AutoComplete is set through `data-ignore-case`.
>
> Options which start with `data` do not require an additional `"data"` in the attribute name. For example, the `dataTextField` option is set through the `data-text-field` attribute and `dataSource` is set through the `data-source` attribute

For more information, see [Setting the data Options](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/mvvm-initialization#setting-the-data-options). See [working demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ijaGuYiZ) here.

Comment: @FranckG. you're welcome. If this has solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as useful and / or accepting it as the solution.